# Minecraft 1.14 - how detect blocks at some distance from the player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This will be my first question here about some work I would do for a world that I'm creating. Let's jump into the question.

**EASY MODE**

I would be able to detect if player is in "range" of a specified block (aka mycelium). If the player has a distance of max 1, I need to spawn some particles around the player. For now, I found a tedious way to do this, but it's not covering all the cases. At the end, I post some images that explain the area mycelium should cover and cases when detection must work. **ATTENTION:** there is no single block of mycelium. Almost all the world will be covered in mycelium!

**How I achieve that *now*?**

For every direction, i have a commandblock checking for player, in a clock. For instance, to detect a player on the top of mycelium I used:

```
execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:mycelium run particle minecraft:happy_villager ~ ~ ~ 1 1 1 1 10 force
```

This will repeat for every variation. So if I want to detect one step forward or backward, I'll do `~1 ~-1 ~` or `~-1 ~-1 ~`, moving the X or the Z coordinate.

Making this for mycelium, it takes for now 5 commandblocks in the clock, and it's not covering, for example, the block above, the corners and the block near, since it will add 6 more commandblocks.

**So i started experimenting**

I know there is a property of objects, called distance. I tried to put `@a[distance=..3]` or `@s[distance=..3]`, but the command just stops to work.

**And now I'm here**

Since I lost many of my time searching, and since is all very confusing because of the 1.13/1.12/1.8 versions, I decided to post an official question.

**FINAL OBJECTIVE (put all things I wanted to do toghether)**

I want to detect if a mycelium block is 1 block away from the player, in every direction. If yes, I would be able to:

1. Play a sound sequence, made with other commandblocks, to **that** player (only for that player, or in that position)
2. Apply particle effect in that position
3. Poison and hurt the player

Mycelium will cover almost all the world, so I cannot test for only "specific" positions or make markers. EVERY single mycelium block must be detected, and if detected, must do that sequence of actions at least once.

[image: Detection area of mycelium]
[image: Where detection must work]

Answer (score 1):

There is no easier way than what you tried. `@e` and other selectors only work for entities, not blocks.
I have made a complicated system in the past that would allow you to do something similar, but (it's not updated to 1.13 and) it would need quite a bit of setup and would create much more lag than simply typing in the 27 commands for your system.